# Some web sites hang on TLS handshake

Tags: ssl

I just changed from a Centurylink-provided wireless access point to using a Linux server to connect to Centurylink's network.

Some web sites seem to hang on TLS handshakes, notably kahoot.it and duckduckgo.com. Firefox on Linux, Lynx on Linux, Chrome on Windows and curl all hang. This curl command is the most info I can get:

```
135 % curl -v https://duckduckgo.com
*   Trying 40.89.244.232:443...
* Connected to duckduckgo.com (40.89.244.232) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to duckduckgo.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to duckduckgo.com:443
```

Oddly, `openssl s_client kahoot.it:443` works.

https://kahoot.com works, https://google.com works, most other web sites work.

What on earth is going on here?

Here's some server details: Arch linux, 5.9.16.a-1-hardened kernel.

Because it's Centurylink, I had to set the VLAN ID to 201:
`ip link add link eno3 name eno3.201 type vlan id 201`.

I've got the server using PPPoE as per the Arch linux wiki on PPPoE.

I have IPv4 forwarding turned on, and IPv4 NAT enabled, here's an excerpt from the systemd unit file for getting the networking going:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/modprobe iptable_nat
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
ExecStart=/usr/bin/iptables -A FORWARD -o eno3 -i eno1 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
ExecStart=/usr/bin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.10.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
ExecStart=/usr/bin/iptables -A FORWARD -o eno3 -i eno2 -s 10.0.10.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
ExecStart=/usr/bin/iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

The server has network devices eno1, eno2, eno3, eno4. Nothing is connected to eno4 eno3 is the device on which I have pppd doing its work:

```
# ip -br l
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno1             UP             44:a8:42:2d:c2:55 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno2             UP             44:a8:42:2d:c2:56 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno3             UP             44:a8:42:2d:c2:57 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno4             DOWN           44:a8:42:2d:c2:58 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> 
eno3.201@eno3    UP             44:a8:42:2d:c2:57 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
ppp0             UNKNOWN        <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> 
[root@monarch ~]# ip -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
eno1             UP             10.0.0.1/24 fe80::46a8:42ff:fe2d:c255/64 
eno2             UP             10.0.10.1/24 fe80::46a8:42ff:fe2d:c256/64 
eno3             UP             fe80::46a8:42ff:fe2d:c257/64 
eno4             DOWN           
eno3.201@eno3    UP             fe80::46a8:42ff:fe2d:c257/64 
ppp0             UNKNOWN        71.33.205.38 peer 207.225.112.2/32
```

Comment: *"... using a Linux server ..."* - There is no such thing as a generic Linux server. I have no idea what this Linux server is doing, i.e. what software is running on it, how it is configured, what tasks it should do etc and how any of this might accidentally or by purpose infer with the traffic. Essentially the only information the question provides is "I've made some unspecific changes to the network and now it does not properly work anymore" - which is not very helpful to debug a problem.

Comment: Edited to add information about the server, as per expert's request. Got any ideas?

Comment: Ah, it's not only a wireless access point but it is actually doing PPP to the internet. My guess is that the MTU of this link is wrong - which might result in some sites working (smaller packets) and others not (larger packets). See [Change mtu of ppp0](https://serverfault.com/q/557349/208324) or [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/mtu-issues.html) for more information and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - that's something I hadn't thought of, but alas, it's not the case. The ppp0 device got its MTU automatically from the PPP setup, somehow. When I cancelled the PPPoE connection and restarted it, it came up with 1484 instead of 1492, and the problem persisted. Changing MTU on the other interfaces to match didn't help either. The problem does not occur on the linux server, so it's something with IPv4 forwarding or the NAT settings. This does narrow the scope.

Comment: Have you actually tried to set the MTU on ppp0 to a lower value? The second link I gave talks of some ISP needing 1460, [this link](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-optimize-pppoe-connections/170505851231244/) recommends 1452.

Comment: The problem exists whether pppd is running or not. I turned off pppd, and plugged in my old C4000xg wireless access point/PPP router. All sites are accessible on the Linux server in question, but not all sites are available for NATted hosts routed by the linux server. I'll certainly keep the MTU in mind, but it looks like something else is at issue.

Comment: It might be useful then to make the packet capture and analyze these. Focus especially on cases where packets get lost (i.e. no ACK from server for this sequence, repeated retries). Another thing which comes to mind: maybe it is some IPv6 vs. IPv4 thing, i.e. your linux server announcing support for IPv6 and resolving DNS names accordingly, even though the uplink can only do IPv4.

Answer (score 2):

I found an idea in the Arch Linux wiki, entry for ppp:

> The MTU under pppoe is 1492 bytes. Most sites use an MTU of 1500. So
> your connection sends an ICMP 3:4 (fragmentation needed) packet,
> asking for a smaller MTU, but some sites have their firewall blocking
> that.

The command to implement PMTU clamping in iptables is:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

This worked for my setup, where `pppd` creates the ppp0 network device.